# Sticky Sidebar - Scroll Through Sidebar Then Stick

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I have looked through multiple SO answers/solutions and tried [stickyMojo](http://mojotech.github.com/stickymojo/) (jquery plugin).

From what I have found, they all have the same failing criteria.

When the sidebar content exceeds the height of the viewport size, the user most scroll down to the end of the main content before they can "finish" scrolling through the sidebar's content.

As an example, what seems to happen is all of the solutions use the footer div and a fixed top position for the sidebar. So, until the user scrolls down enough to where the sidebar's bottom hits the top of the footer div, they have not seen all of the sidebar's content.

As an example of what I am trying to achieve - [Google Plus Home](https://plus.google.com/) try viewing your Google+ home page and look at the sidebar on the right. As you scroll through content, you instantly start scrolling through the sidebar content, until you reach the end of the sidebar content and then it becomes fixed (it cuts off the top of the sidebar content) so seemingly they are using the bottom of the viewport and the bottom of the sidebar as the reference point instead of the top.

How can I achieve this same effect and have it be crossbrowser compliant? Plugin or Jquery code either work and would be appreciated!